# How to replace an item in a list depending on an item in another list?

Tags: python, list

I have two equal lists, their values are connected to each other:

```
list1 = [29, 4, 15, 4, 5, 5]
list2 = [57.49999999999999, 89.74358974358975, 78.94736842105263, 100.0, 94.44444444444444, 57.89473684210527]
```

How do I change the i-th value in `list1` to `40` if the corresponding i-th value in `list2` is less than `65.0`?

Comment: Take a look at `zip`

Answer (score 2):

A list comprehension with the ternary operator and `zip` should do the trick:

```
[40 if list2_val < 65.0 else list1_val
    for list1_val, list2_val in zip(list1, list2)]
Out[2]: [40, 4, 15, 4, 5, 40]
```

FWIW, this more compact (but perhaps more difficult to read) syntax will produce an identical result to that of [Tobias's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46975285/5015569).

Depending on how long your lists are, you might try using `pandas` and `numpy`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'list1': list1, 'list2': list2})
>>> df
   list1       list2
0     29   57.500000
1      4   89.743590
2     15   78.947368
3      4  100.000000
4      5   94.444444
5      5   57.894737
>>> df['list1_new'] = np.where(df['list2'] < 65, 40, df['list1'])
   list1       list2  list1_new
0     29   57.500000         40
1      4   89.743590          4
2     15   78.947368         15
3      4  100.000000          4
4      5   94.444444          5
5      5   57.894737         40
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `zip` as I wrote in a comment, I think that would be the cleanest solution.

```
new_list1 = []
for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
    if b < 65.0:
        new_list1.append(40)
    else:
        new_list1.append(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to iterate on list2 to find which index has a value smaller than 65.0. With this index number you can replace nth value in list1:

```
list1 = [29, 4, 15, 4, 5, 5]
list2 = [57.49999999999999, 89.74358974358975, 78.94736842105263, 100.0, 
94.44444444444444, 57.89473684210527]

for i in range(0, len(list1)):

  if list2[i] < 65.0:
    list1[i] = 40


print(list1)
```